# couldn't get memberof with JSdoc

Tags: function, parsing, prototype, jsdoc

```
Student.prototype.getStudentName = function(id) {
/**
 * @function getStudentName
 * @description returns student name.
 * @param [id] 
 * @memberof Student
 **/
```

};

Although I add a `memberof` tag, parser cannot parse the `Student` while other tags(`function`, `description` and `param`) works just fine.
offical documentation is here; http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html

How should I update the function so it returns `getStudentName` as a member of `Student`?

Should I edit the `@function` tag as; `Student.getStudentName`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use **@memberof** *modulename* you must have **@module** *modulename* defined.

```
/**
 * @module Student
 */

...

Student.prototype.getStudentName = function(id) {
/**
 * @function getStudentName
 * @description returns student name.
 * @param [id] 
 * @memberof Student
 **/
```